# Not able to move to next line when enter is hit in textarea

Tags: salesforce

I'm stuck here with the problem of not able to move to next line when I hit enter in a text area

This is the code I've used for text area:

```
<apex:inputTextarea id="Ascp"  rows="5" value="{!mNC.newCase.desc}" 
styleClass="form-control right-section pull-none" html-placeholder=" 
{!$Label.test_label}"/>
```

Please help!

Comment: Is there some js code that is preventing that from occurring or some styling element?

Comment: No @GarethJordan :(

Comment: Please check your css classes in "styleClass", maybe some of them blocking the new line. Try remove classes one by one.